# Value of None or ValueError("Invalid JSON file.")

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, iot

I'm setting up SNS push notifications on AWS IoT for two MCU sensors.

Right now I am getting alerts just when the moisture is low so I wanted to include temp/humidity data but its either giving me a value of none or throwing an error Invalid JSON.  How do I fix this?

Working code:

```
def myShadowUpdateCallback(payload, responseStatus, token):
  print()
  print('UPDATE: $aws/things/' + SHADOW_HANDLER +
    '/shadow/update/#')
  print("payload = " + payload)
  print("responseStatus = " + responseStatus)
  print("token = " + token)

channel = 21
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)

while True:

  if GPIO.input(channel):
    myDeviceShadow.shadowUpdate(
      '{"state":{"reported":{"moisture":"low"}}}',
      myShadowUpdateCallback, 5)
  else:
    myDeviceShadow.shadowUpdate(
      '{"state":{"reported":{"moisture":"okay"}}}',
      myShadowUpdateCallback, 5)
```

E-mail result:

```
{"state":{"reported":{"moisture":"low"}},"metadata":{"reported":{"moisture":{"timestamp":1548870624}}},"version":5167,"timestamp":1548870624,"clientToken":"b8a2"}
```

To get the DH22 temp/humidity sensor working I added:

```
import Adafruit_DHT

humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, 20)
```

Changed:

```
def myShadowUpdateCallback(payload, responseStatus, token):
  print()
  print('UPDATE: $aws/things/' + SHADOW_HANDLER +
    '/shadow/update/#')
  print("payload = " + payload)
  print("responseStatus = " + responseStatus)
  print("token = " + token)
  print('Temperature={}*F  Humidity={}%'.format(temperature, humidity))

while True:

  if GPIO.input(channel):
    myDeviceShadow.shadowUpdate(
      '{"state":{"reported":{"moisture":"low","humidity":{"0":"0.1f"},"temperature":{"1":"0.1f"}}}}',
      myShadowUpdateCallback, 5)
  else:
    myDeviceShadow.shadowUpdate(
      '{"state":{"reported":{"moisture":"okay","humidity":{"0":"0.1f"},"temperature":{"1":"0.1f"}}}}',
      myShadowUpdateCallback, 5)
```

Error:

When moisture is OK the temperature and moisture show:

```
Temperature=None*F  Humidity=None%
```

When moisture is low I get an error:

```
myShadowUpdateCallback, ValueError: Invalid JSON file.
```

Comment: maybe you can check around the line which raised the exception to see why it happens. Sometimes there are comments or obvious checks; The source is often very readable in those high level packages

Comment: You should use `lower_case_with_underscores` instead of `camelCase` for variable and function names in python. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the part {0:0.1f} is no valid json.
Maybe change it to something like {"0":"0.1f"} or other valid json.